# Python.h header file missing on Mac OS X 10.6

Tags: python, xcode, macos, osx-snow-leopard, header-files

I'm trying to access a shared C library in Python with `ctypes` on Mac OS X 10.6.8 with Python 2.7.4. To do this, I need to `#include <Python.h>` in my C code. If I try to compile a C script that only has that one include statement in it, call it "sample.c", I get:

```
$ gcc -shared -o sample.so sample.c
sample.c:1:20: error: Python.h: No such file or directory
```

Since I'm running Mac 10.6, I have Xcode 3.2.6, the latest version available on this iteration of OS X without paying to upgrade to 10.7 and getting Xcode 4. Is there a way to get the Python header file without upgrading my OS?

Comment: *Either* use `ctypes` *or* write your library as a Python extension (using `Python.h`). Doing both is rarely a good idea.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Python is a framework on Mac OS X so you need to,

```
#include <Python/Python.h>
```

You also need to call `gcc` with the `-framework` argument to actually do anything inside C,

```
gcc -shared -o sample.so sample.c -framework Python
```

Comment: The convention is: use `#include <Python.h>` and set the right `-I`-path to  Python-headers (as other answers here have explained, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074274/5769463). Prefixing includes with `<Python/` will not work as soon as third party libraries are used (which most probably would use the standard convention).

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about 10.6.8, but `Python.h` should be in

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

if you installed the official python.org binary. Try adding

```
-I/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7
```

to your `gcc` command and see if that works.

Answer (score 4):

In case you have installed Python using Brew, it may be worthwhile to check the location of where your headers are. 
Try `I/usr/local/Cellar/python/...`

Comment: My full path was: `I/usr/local/Cellar/python@3.9/3.9.6/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers`

Answer (score 2):

Another way is to add `` `python-config --include` `` to the `gcc` call. It will expand to `-I/usr/...`, so

```
gcc -shared -o sample.so sample.c `python-config --include`
```

Also other options can be retrieved, such as `` `python-config --cflags --ldflags` ``.

`python-config` or `python3-config` is typically available after `brew install python`. Backticks are `bash`-specific. To see what it would output (e.g., when one doesn't use `bash`) use

```
python-config --include
```

Comment: please provide what `python-config` a non-standard module that doesn't currently work with 3.8, would output.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was solved by install Xcode command line tools with:

```
xcode-select --install
```