# Where does brew install the Python headers?

Tags: python, python-3.x, homebrew, cython

I am trying to compile a simple "Hello, World!" in Cython. In a file I have:

```
print("Hello, World!")
```

I run:

```
cython hello_world.pyx
```

To get the `hello_world.c` file. I then try:

```
gcc -c hello_world.c
```

Which gives the error:

```
fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
```

Then I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16454614/667648):

```
gcc -c hello_world.c -framework Python
```

Didn't work. I had changed `include "Python.h"` to `<Python/Python.h>` and got a different error:

```
fatal error: 'longintrepr.h' file not found
```

Regardless, I want to use Python3, not the Python Apple ships with, but I am unable to figure out where the Python3 development headers are located.

Ultimately, I want to be able to compile `hello_world.c` so that it works in a Python3 interpreter.

(I am using brew's python3.5.2_1, if that helps.)

Comment: Have you tried simply `whereis` the python executable you are using? IIRC the path is something along the lines of `/usr/local/bin` and brew installs headers in `/usr/local/include`. Unfortunately I don't have a mac anymore so I can't check

Comment: On Linux you need to install python-dev. Perhaps the same is required with brew.

Comment: check if it here /usr/local/Cellar/python/<PYTHON_VERSION>/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/<VERSION>/include/python<VERSION>/Python.h

Comment: @sr3z: Not quite but close enough for me to figure it out! Thanks! Pretty much off by the letter `m` lol.

Comment: The linux 'find' command is great for... finding things.  It's kind of complicated, but it's well worth the trouble to learn how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Going off from @sr3z's comment, doing:

```
gcc -c random_sum.c -I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.5.2_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.5/include/python3.5m
```

Creates `random_sum.o`.

Answer (score 2):

Currently is `/usr/local/Frameworks/Python.framework/Headers`.

Comment: For anyone else who lands here the answer is correct but just be aware the path above is a symlink to another directory