# Qt: Undefined symbols when trying to use python.h in qt

Tags: python, c++, macos, qt, compiler-errors

I am doing some tiny work with Qt on Mac. I need to call a python function in my main function. But when I try to call Py_initialize() as everyone said, compiler throws a error like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
  _main in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see 
invocation)
make: *** [video.app/Contents/MacOS/video] Error 1
07:48:07: The process "/usr/bin/make" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project video (kit: Desktop Qt 5.8.0 
clang 64bit)
When executing step "Make"
```

My code is trivial and there should not be anything weird about this. Here it is:

```
// bunch of headers
#include <python2.7/Python.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

Py_Initialize();

QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

QQmlApplicationEngine engine;

QQmlComponent component(&engine, QUrl(QStringLiteral("qrc:///main.qml")));
QObject *object = component.create();
QObject *mainForm = object->findChild<QObject*>("mainForm");

SignalNexus sn;

QObject::connect(mainForm, SIGNAL(populateToken(QString)), &sn, SLOT(pushToPipe(QString)));

QObject::connect(&sn, SIGNAL(populateResult(QVariant, QVariant)), mainForm, SLOT(handleResult(QVariant, QVariant)));
return app.exec();
}
```

When I comment the Py_initalize() line, everything works fine. I figure that this is something to do with OSx. But I really don't know how to fix this thing. Help needed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your include line to this

```
// bunch of headers
 #include <Python/Python.h>

using namespace std;


int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{

Py_Initialize();
```

Comment: Cool, it works. Can you give me a brief explanation? Thx!

Comment: Yes of course! Python is already a framework on Mac OS X! So you actually inside C don't need to do anything :)

Comment: You could see more here if you want a better explain from people with more expertise than me http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454129/python-h-header-file-missing-on-mac-os-x-10-6

Comment: The pleasure is mine! Always loved to help