# c++: can't find numpy/arrayobject.h and Python.h

Tags: c++, path, environment-variables, cython

I'm trying to compile the following c++ file

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <Python.h>
#include <numpy/npy_math.h>
 
using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 
 
   cout << "Hello World" << endl;    // prints value of i 
}
```

with the following

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++1y
```

It returns:      main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found

Then I found this solution

[Python.h header file missing on Mac OS X 10.6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454129/python-h-header-file-missing-on-mac-os-x-10-6)

then I change the file into

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <Python/Python.h>
#include <numpy/npy_math.h>

using namespace std; 
int main() 
{ 

   cout << "Hello World" << endl;    // prints value of i 
}
```

It works, but second problem comes out:  main.cpp:3:10: fatal error: 'numpy/npy_math.h' file not found

Ok, then I find the path of numpy and

```
clang++ main.cpp -std=c++1y -I /Users/nicolas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include
```

then, it returns

/Users/nicolas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/npy_common.h:11:10: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
#include <Python.h>

Can anyone help me?

Comment: That would be the right answer from the duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59074274/5769463 or https://stackoverflow.com/a/16454458/5769463

Answer (score 1):

You can quickfix this by opening `npy_common.h` and changing `#include <Python.h>` to either `#include <Python/Python.h>` or `#include <../../Python/Python.h>` or whatever is the relative path to that file, or even copy the file Python.h to `Users/nicolas/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/numpy/` folder

The reason the file is not found is because npy_common.h is looking for Python.h in the same directory

Comment: Thanks bro. but then I have to change all the header file one by one,  is there any better way to fix this?