# Golang Embedding Python in Go

Tags: python-3.x, go, cgo

I've been reading the articles [embedding-python-in-go](https://medium.com/poweruserblog/embedding-python-in-go-338c0399f3d5) and the original article [packaging-python-code](https://www.ardanlabs.com/blog/2020/08/packaging-python-code.html), but I have yet to succeed at running Python.h through cgo.

Can this be done on an m1 mac? if not, should I port everything into a Linux docker container?

what am I missing when setting up this type of project.

below is a simple example from article 1.
This leads to the error

`./main.go:22:4: could not determine kind of name for C.PyRun_SimpleString`

```
 1 package main
 2 /*
 3  #cgo pkg-config: python3
 #include <Python/Python.h>
 4 */
 5 import "C"
 6
 7 import (
 8   "unsafe"
 9 )
10 
11 func main() {
12
13   pycodeGo := `
14 import sys
15 for path in sys.path:
16   print(path)
17 ` 
18   
19   defer C.Py_Finalize()
20   C.Py_Initialize()
21   pycodeC := C.CString(pycodeGo)
22   defer C.free(unsafe.Pointer(pycodeC))
23   C.PyRun_SimpleString(pycodeC)
24 
25 }
```

removing lines 20-23 returns error

```
# command-line-arguments
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_Py_Finalize", referenced from:
      __cgo_672c0788d500_Cfunc_Py_Finalize in _x002.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_672c0788d500_Cfunc_Py_Finalize)
  "_Py_Initialize", referenced from:
      __cgo_672c0788d500_Cfunc_Py_Initialize in _x002.o
     (maybe you meant: __cgo_672c0788d500_Cfunc_Py_Initialize)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [run] Error 2
```

kinda at a lost on the architecture error; m1 issue?

importing python.h on mac is #include <Python/Python.h> instead of #include <Python.h> [importing Python.h on mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16454129/python-h-header-file-missing-on-mac-os-x-10-6)

software specs

$ python3 -V Python 3.9.10

$ go version go version go1.17.8 darwin/arm64

macOS verrsion 11.4, M1 2020.

Python.h is present under/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/Library/Frameworks/Python3.framework/Versions/3.8/Headers/Python.h

reference git repos [ardanlabs/python-go](https://github.com/ardanlabs/python-go) [go-python3](https://github.com/DataDog/go-python3) [christian-korneck/python-go](https://github.com/christian-korneck/python-go)

Comment: Update: A Docker image running golang:1.9-stretch
 and python3-dev also resolved int the error. 

/dev_main.go:24:4: could not determine kind of name for C.PyRun_SimpleString

Answer (score 0):

Go's CGO implementation + their error messages is a challenging beast when you first use it.

The rule with CGO and doing C/C++ include's is you have to follow your include with the import "C" otherwise you get no clue as to what you've done wrong.  So update your include/import to this:

```
// #include <Python.h>
import "C"
```