# Error installing tbb on MacOS using homebrew

Tags: python, macos, cmake, homebrew, tbb

I'm trying to install **tbb** on MacOS using Homebrew, and I get the following error message:

```
==> cmake --build build/shared
Last 15 lines from /Users/inspectorgloomy/Library/Logs/Homebrew/tbb/02.cmake:
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/make  -f python/CMakeFiles/python_build.dir/build.make python/CMakeFiles/python_build.dir/build
[100%] Build and install to work directory the oneTBB Python module
cd /tmp/tbb-20240201-34715-juqzow/oneTBB-2021.11.0/build/shared/python && /usr/local/bin/python3 python_build/setup.py build -bpython_build build_ext -I/tmp/tbb-20240201-34715-juqzow/oneTBB-2021.11.0/src/tbb/../../include -L/tmp/tbb-20240201-34715-juqzow/oneTBB-2021.11.0/build/shared/appleclang_13.0_cxx11_64_release install --prefix build --install-lib python_build/build/lib/python3.12/site-packages -f
tbb/api_wrap.cpp:199:11: fatal error: 'Python.h' file not found
# include <Python.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
Environment specifies CC=clang CXX=clang++
Warning: TBBROOT env var is not set and Intel's compiler is not used. It might lead
    !!!: to compile/link problems. Source tbbvars.sh/.csh file to set environment
error: command '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/mac/super/clang' failed with exit code 1
make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_build] Error 1
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_build.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

It looks like CMake can't find *Python.h* for some reason. I can build other packages just fine, it only happens with **tbb**. I have Python installed.

For context, I'm trying to install **tbb** in order to install **openvino**. I'm running MacOS 11.7.10.

Comment: When you run `xcode-select --version`, what version do you get? What about when you run `which apxs` and `which apxs2`?

Comment: Have you run `brew doctor`? Is it clear?

Comment: @xTerrene: `xcode-select version 2384`, `apxs not found`, `apxs2 not found`.

Comment: @AlexReinking: `brew doctor` doesn't return anything (apart from the standard warning about using MacOS 11.)

Answer (score 0):

Based on a [similar question posted as an issue in a repository](https://github.com/GrahamDumpleton/mod_wsgi/issues/258), it looks like this is looking for something XCode provides; [another StackOverflow question has an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74220321/10117098) saying something similar. Ensure you have XCode's latest version installed ***via the App Store***, and it might not hurt to also try getting Python's dev packages also (as the StackOverflow question linked has an answer mentioning).